# Windows rmdir fails when run in R system() function

Tags: r, windows

When I run the following command at the Windows 11 Command Prompt it works:

```
rmdir /s /q C:\_studies\assess_strategy
```

However, when I run it from within the R 'system' function I get the following feedback:

```
system("rmdir /s /q C:\\_studies\\assess_strategy")
/usr/bin/rmdir: failed to remove '/s': No such file or directory
/usr/bin/rmdir: failed to remove '/q': No such file or directory
/usr/bin/rmdir: failed to remove 'C:\_studies\assess_strategy': Directory not empty
```

I've tried escaping /s and /q but that doesn't help:

```
system("rmdir \\/s \\/q C:\\_studies\\assess_strategy")
```

I get the same feedback as previously.

What can I do to get this to work?

By the way, I've also tried the R unlink command. That also fails.

Comment: In path you escape backslashes but flags don't have these, try `system("rmdir /s /q C:\\_studies\\assess_strategy")`.

Comment: “That also fails.” — Well, post the code you tried to run. `unlink()` works. `system()` probably fails because it is not running the shell you think it is running, and consequently `rmdir` is not the command you think it is, as explained by the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `/usr/bin/rmdir` in recieved error I assume it's not the `rmdir` you were expecting. It's probably from Git Bash, does not understand `/s /q` keys and
removes only empty directories.
`rmdir` / `rd` is an internal command, so try to invoke it through `shell()` instead:

```r
shell("rmdir /s /q C:\\_studies\\assess_strategy")
```

For `unlink()`, make sure you have `recursive` enabled:

```r
unlink("C:\\_studies\\assess_strategy"", recursive = TRUE)
```

Or just use `fs::dir_delete()`

Comment: Thanks, the shell command does the trick. I'm not sure what you mean by fs::dir_delete(). Can you explain this? Is this something I can execute from within R?

Comment: it's `dir_delete()` function from `fs` package - https://fs.r-lib.org/reference/delete.html